# Angular2 get current route object like ng-route's toState param

Tags: angularjs, typescript

```
@RouteConfig([
{
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
{
    path: '/search',
    name: 'Search',
    component: SearchComponent,
    needAuth: true
},
{
    path: '/result/:searchString',
    name: 'Result',
    component: ResultComponent,
    needAuth: true
},
{path: '/**', redirectTo: ['Login']}
])
```

I have a config as this, how can I detect current route object like;

```
{
    path: '/result/:searchString',
    name: 'Result',
    component: ResultComponent,
    needAuth: true
}
```

for route restriction when user not logged in.

I want to make like this;

```
export class AppComponent {
constructor(private _authService:AuthenticationService) {
    if (this._authService.getUser() != null && CURRENT ROUTE OBJECT's needAuth PROPERTY is TRUE) {
        this._router.navigate(['Search'])
    } else {
        this._router.navigate(['Login'])
    }
}
```

}

All kind of helps are welcome.

**************UPDATE********************

I found this solution

```
        this._router.subscribe((url) => {
        this._router.recognize(url).then((instruction) => {
            if(this._authService.getUser() == null && instruction.component.routeData.data.needAuth) {
                this._router.navigate(['Login'])
            }

            if(this._authService.getUser() !=null && !instruction.component.routeData.data.needAuth) {
                this._router.navigate(['Search'])
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
needAuth: true
```

in the `RouteConfig` use

```
data: {needAuth: true}
```

then inject it

```
constructor(private routeData: RouteData) {
  if(routeData.needAuth) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried that but it only returns the path parameter, I need whole object to catch custom 'key':'value' like needAuth:true

Comment: Thanks but I won't work, cause RouteData only used for set parameters to child route.

I found another fix but it's ugly.

Comment: I see. I don't think it's too ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could extend the `RouterOutlet` class to intercept the route activation in a global way:

```
import {Directive} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouterOutlet, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';

@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})

export class MyOwnRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
  (...)

  activate(oldInstruction: ComponentInstruction) {
    var url = this.parentRouter.lastNavigationAttempt;
    console.log('attemping to nav');
    if (oldInstruction.routeData.needAuth && !this.authService.loggedIn){
      var newInstruction = new ComponentInstruction('Login', [], new RouteData(), Login, false, 1);
      return super.activate(newInstruction);
    } else {
      return super.activate(oldInstruction);
    }
  }
}
```

You need to configure routes this way:

```
{
  path: '/result/:searchString',
  name: 'Result',
  component: ResultComponent,
  data: {
    needAuth: true
  }
}
```

See these links for more details:

- [Angular 2 Cancelling Route Navigation on UnAuthenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968386/angular-2-cancelling-route-navigation-on-unauthenticate/35968606#35968606)
- https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/25/angular-2-series-part-4-component-router-in-depth/

Comment: I couldn't get it work. But found another solution. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: What is the problem?